# How to instantiate DbContext from IHostingService

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class that derives from `BackgroundService` (`IHostedService`) for running background tasks. This will be added to my services using `builder.Services.AddHostedService<BackgroundTaskService>()`

`BackgroundService`'s task runs for the entire duration of the web application, checking for queued data to process.

My question is, how do I instantiate an instance of `DbContext` from this code?

I could have the `BackgroundTaskService` constructor accept a `DbContext`. But wouldn't that keep the `DbContext` open forever?

And how else could I instantiate it without duplicating all the code to scan my settings file for the connection string, etc.?

Comment: Docs - [DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) - [Using a DbContext factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recemmended approach is to inject `IDbContextFactory<TContext>` as described in the following article: [Using a DbContext factory (e.g. for Blazor)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)

> Some application types (e.g. ASP.NET Core Blazor) use dependency injection but do not create a service scope that aligns with the desired DbContext lifetime. Even where such an alignment does exist, the application may need to perform multiple units-of-work within this scope. For example, multiple units-of-work within a single HTTP request.
>
> In these cases, AddDbContextFactory can be used to register a factory for creation of DbContext instances.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test"));
}
```

Then in your controller:

```cs
private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _contextFactory;

public MyController(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory)
{
    _contextFactory = contextFactory;
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to have a link to the article you referenced?

Comment: Oh, thank you @JonathanWood for noticing it. Added the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scope service factory. [Check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) for reference.

Here you have an example:

```
// Injection
public class DataApi : BackgroundService
{
  private readonly ILogger<DataApi> logger;
  private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

  public DataApi(ILogger<DataApi> _logger, IConfiguration _cfg, IServiceScopeFactory _sSF)
  {
    logger = _logger;
    scopeFactory = _sSF;
    // e.g. data from appsettings.json 
    // var recovery = _cfg["Api:Recovery"];
  }
// ...
```

```
// Usage
protected async Task DataCollector()
{
  logger.LogInformation("Collector");

  using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
  {
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

    var myList = await db.MyEntity
      .AsNoTracking()
      .Where(t => t.active)
      .ToListAsync();

    if (myList.Count == 0)
    {
      logger.LogInformation("Empty...");
      return;
    }
  // logic...
  }

  await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```