# C# This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .a

I am getting an error in the system, what is the reason? I wasn't getting such errors in .NET 5.

[image: Exception location]

[image: Exception text]

I've never encountered such a problem in APIs, I'm actually pretty new to async methods, can someone enlighten me :)
I translated `AsQueryable` to filter later

```cs
private DataContext _Context;
private IFileUpload _File;

public ProductRepository(DataContext Context, IFileUpload file) : base(Context)
{
    _Context = Context;
    _File = file;
}

public async Task<Product> GetProductByUrl(string ProductUrl, bool tracking = false)
{
    var Model = _Context.Products
        .Include(i => i.ProductPictures)
        .Include(i => i.MyProperty)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.Category)
        .AsQueryable();
    if (!tracking)
    {
        Model = Model.AsNoTracking();
    }
    return await Model.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Url == ProductUrl);
}
```

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of code. Please add the code into the question itself.

Comment: Please provide the code from where you are calling `GetProductByUrl`, ideally up to the controller. You might be starting two tasks in parallel, not awaiting the result of the first one. Actually it's possible to run multiple tasks in parallel, but using different instances of `DbContext`. In this case you need to inject `IDbContextFactory<TContext>` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75193413/822455 for details)

Comment: Agree with @MikeMozhaev `DbContext` is not designed for multi-threading .. use different instances, e.g. by `IDbContextFactory<TContext>`. Although in this case, it looks like you have your DI configured wrong. There should be only 1 DbContext instance per request